# High performance RSA implementation for C# or C

Tags: c#, c, performance, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have an webservice that performs many RSA-signature operations. I use the CryptograhyProvider from .net. This uses the unmanaged CyptoAPI from Windows.

I often have this error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Der RPC-Server
>   ist für diesen Vorgang zu stark ausgelastet.  [=The rpc server is too
>   busy to complete the transaction]
>
> bei
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32
>   hr)    bei
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportKey(SafeProvHandle hCSP,
>   Int32 keyNumber, CspProviderFlags flags, Object cspObject,
>   SafeKeyHandle& hKey)    bei
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(RSAParameters
>   parameters)

Instead of trying to fix this, I'd rather replace my RSA-signing operation with an DLLImport to a high performance RSA C implementation.

Does someone know one or can recommend one?

Is OpenSSL faster than MS CryptoApi?
I also suspect that loading the key might cause serious overhead.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization to me. If you think you want better performance then you first must measure the performance of your existing RSA implementation. Then determine the performance you need to have. You will be unlikely to find a software RSA implementation that is even 2x better than MS's.

Comment: Hardware matters here, too. Crypto acceleration modules are good stuff (though if you're only signing things, the RNGs in them won't matter). Compiling your crypto library with some optimization flags set for your target processor will make a difference too.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend OpenSSL but i dont know the comparison with MS CryptoAPI. Its simple to use and documentation is extensive along with sample source code.

Check the detailed description of the APIs [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html#).

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider [NSS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/). [This](http://idlebox.net/2008/0714-cryptography-speedtest-comparison/) is 2 years old, but could still be worth perusing.

Comment: Thanks! But they unfortunately only test symmetric algorithms, not RSA

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cryptopp.com/
might be a good library.

It was used in this speed test:
http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html

Unfortunately there is no comparison with OpenSSL available